# Flags or a separate method for each flag possible value?

Tags: java

If you want to get at some point both negative or positive numbers from an array, which option would be 'better':


`getAllNumbers(initialArray, boolean positive)
....`


or


`getAllPositiveNumbers(initialArray){


....

}

getAllNegativeNumbers(initialArray){

...

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to use `getAllPositiveNumbers` and `getAllNegativeNumbers` since the code is more clear to read, but it might be reasonable to provide a convenience method for clients.

If the client code must select one of the methods at runtime (because of user input). Then every client must do something like this:

```
boolean selectPositiveNumber = .....; // obtained somehow through user input
int[] numbers = null;
if(positiveNumbers){
     numbers = getAllPositiveNumbers(allNumbers);
} else {
     numbers = getAllNegativeNumbers(allNumbers);
}
```

In this case the convenience method `getAllNumbers(initialArray, boolean positive)` makes the client code easier.

```
boolean selectPositiveNumber = .....; // obtained somehow through user input
int[] numbers = getAllNumbers(allNumbers, selectPositiveNumber);
```

If the client code selects one of the methods at 'compile time'. Then the client doesn't need a convenience method, e.g. a client code might do something like this:

```
public int positiveSum(int[] values){
   int[] positiveNumbers = getPositiveNumbers(values);

   int sum = 0;
   // loop to calc the sum
   return sum;
}
```

Fortunately you can combine both:

```
public int[] getAllNumbers(int[] nums, boolean onlyPositiveNums){
    if(onlyPositiveNums){
        return getAllPositiveNumbers(nums);
    } else {
        return getAllNegativeNumbers(nums);
    }
}
```

So if you expect a lot of client code which does an `if/else` than provide a convenience method.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd go for `getAllPositiveNumbers`. Otherwise, you'll need to write a fair few comments in `getAllNumbers` to make it as instantly obvious the former.

**Example**

```
/**
 * Returns numbers from an array.
 * @positive boolean value indicating to get just positive values or not.
 *
 */
 public List<Integer> getAllNumbers(initialArray, boolean positive)
 {
    // Some code.
 }
```

Or

```
 public List<Integer> getAllPositiveNumbers(int[] numbers)
 {
   // Some code.
 }
```

As you can see, the last one is pretty obvious what it does.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a library or something, I'd recommend to use both. The getAllPositiveNumbers and getAllNegativeNumbers methods could call the getAllNumbers method, like so:

```
public int[] getAllNumbers(int[] array, boolean positive) {
    //...
}

public int[] getAllPositiveNumbers(int[] array) {
    return getAllNumbers(array, true);
}
```

Otherwise use whichever you prefer.